# Get Lynis update on Debian Testing (buster)

Tags: debian, security, upgrade

Is there any way I can get [Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) updates if I'm using [Debian Testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) (buster)? I'd rather avoid installing newer version of [Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) manually. I'd like to use Debian repository.

```
root@host:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux testing (buster)
Release:        testing
Codename:       buster
```

[Lynis](https://cisofy.com/lynis/) `update info`:

```
root@host:~# lynis update info

      ===============================================================================
        Lynis update available
      ===============================================================================

        Current version is more than 4 months old

        Please update to the latest version.
        New releases include additional features, bug fixes, tests and baselines.

        Download the latest version:
        Packages (DEB/RPM) -  https://packages.cisofy.com
        Website            -  https://cisofy.com/downloads/
        GitHub             -  https://github.com/CISOfy/lynis

      ===============================================================================


 == Lynis ==

  Version            : 2.5.0
  Status             : Outdated
  Installed version  : 250
  Latest version     : 257
  Release date       : 2017-05-03
  Update location    : https://cisofy.com/lynis/


2007-2017, CISOfy - https://cisofy.com/lynis/
```

I ran `aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade` but currently there are no more updates.

Comment: The only way to do this from the Debian repositories is to install the testing or unstable version, however they may not be completely up to date, unless it is a special case or the developer has a special repo for bleeding edge versions. Otherwise, you are best doing a manual install from source, which will guarantee the latest updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation process is descried on the [official website](https://packages.cisofy.com/community/#debian-ubuntu).

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C80E383C3DE9F082E01391A0366C67DE91CA5D5F
apt install apt-transport-https
echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99disable-translations
echo "deb https://packages.cisofy.com/community/lynis/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cisofy-lynis.list
apt update
apt remove lynis
apt install lynis
```

Verify your version:

```
lynis show version
2.5.7
```